# Hydra brute force ssh usernames with given RSA key

Tags: ssh, brute-force, hydra

On a machine supporting ssh, an RSA key is given but no username.
My idea was brute-forcing the SSH username with Hydra but I didn't find any option to give the RSA key to Hydra.

Is it possible to brute force ssh usernames with an RSA key using Hydra?

Since its a CTF. I'll publish the RSA key:
[image: Screenshot]
[Source](https://arz101.medium.com/tryhackme-wgel-ctf-3557faa036b) (This walkthrough shows the solution for the CTF, still I want to know wheater a username brute-force with the RSA key is possible or not)

Comment: There does not appear to be a function in hydra where you can supply a key/certificate and then only bruteforce the user name.